# Using git submodules with xCode projects

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a project (A), which is partially used as a submodule for another project (B). Both projects are under development.
Part of sources from submodule (A) added to my parent project (B) as links, without copying, so I can update thus files with `git pull` from directory with submodule.

- Q1: Is it a normal workflow, to use submodules in such way?
- Q2: Is there way to automate adding of new files to A, so them automatically
  become parts of B?
- Q3: I have issues after removing submodule code - all its parts displayed as absent in xCode, although everything is compiling and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cocoapods for this purposes. It automates includes and making changes. You can create local pod, just for sharing code, as well, as remote one